# IBM Sterling OMS 9.3

Tags: ibm-sterling

Can someone please tell me about the different folders of IBM Sterling OMS 9.3 i.e. folders :  Properties , Repository , Resources , Temp , external_Deployments , xapidocs ?
If you can also provide me a link to any such documentation? I am not able to find such docummentation on IBM Knowledge Center.

Comment: These folders are the ones that are present in Sterling when we install it on our system.

Answer (score 0):

Your Questions seems more of info question,If you can be more precise and pin point.I can reply better:
**Here are some quick things you can consider:**
**Properties**:This folder contains property config file of the application like any other package you will find properties here.
like for local properties you can find them in customerOverride.properties and basic application level properties you can find in Sandbox.cfg

**Repository** :Will be having various file that may have JS files of all your deployed WAR files like ISCCS,WCS,SMCFS etc (check in eardata)

**Resource**s : Now this is another folder which is package specific folder containing properties of scripts running on your app.Like ant scripts Again generally you may not feel a need of touching this folder.

**Temp** :Again now this folder "TMP" will have details of the packages that you have build in your system and within every build you will see updates here in this folder.Even JS libraries are kepyt here Like Dojo minification details for call center.

**external_Deployments** :This will have your build files which you make take to any server for deployment.(.ear file)

**xapidocs** : this folder is documnetations mentained by IBM where you can check details for all the API's and java classes implemented in package.